# how to add data in datagridview from textbox & save it from datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i am saving data from datagridview to table but There is text box from that will add data data in datagridview & I need to save data in table for particular added row.but it is not showing proper result.

```
private void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String[] row = new String[7];
    row[0] = cmbsfno.SelectedItem.ToString();
    row[1] = cmbstandard.SelectedItem.ToString();
    row[2] = cmbprority.SelectedItem.ToString();
    row[3] = comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString();
    row[4] = cmbpartfamily.SelectedItem.ToString();
    row[5] = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
    row[6] = txtremark.Text;

    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    cnt++;
}
```

when user added some record in datagridview how to save it in table .its saving but textbox data saving properly

Comment: "not showing proper result" what does it show?

Comment: Do you mean you want to save the data to an SQL table?

Comment: I want to save data from datagrid view to table ...but when I will 2 rows in  datagridview it shows the textbox value but i want the value added in datagridview.

Comment: u want to store datagridview datatable or dataset value to sql DB after retrieve for disply on gridview that time only it will working fine,u directly enter and shows mean it will display present txtremark value only..

Comment: suppose for 1st record i have remark as "test" and added data in datagridview & for 2nd time i have added remark "testing"....that time i want result like 1st recod having remark test & 2nd having remark testing.....but now it is showing the value present in textbox remark its because i have added row[6]=txtremark.text.

Comment: i know i need to change something Like row[6]= dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.tosting()...but its not working ..

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String[] row = new String[7];
        dataGridView1.Rows[cnt].Cell[0].value = cmbsfno.SelectedItem.ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[cnt].Cell[1].value = cmbstandard.SelectedItem.ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[cnt].Cell[2].value = cmbprority.SelectedItem.ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[cnt].Cell[3].value = comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[cnt].Cell[4].value = cmbpartfamily.SelectedItem.ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[cnt].Cell[5].value = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[cnt].Cell[6].value = txtremark.Text;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        cnt++;
    }
```

Comment: i dont want txtremark.text value in datagridview 6 row. i want the value added in gridview from datatxtremark to datagridview.when I will add two rows its not showing the added value in datagridview.it showing the result from txtremak.

Comment: I want to replacedataGridView1.Rows[cnt].Cell[6].value = txtremark.Text; to added value of datagridview